# ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "User.jsgGroupName" must be a "JsgGroup" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am getting **ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "User.jsgGroupName" must be a "JsgGroup" instance.** this error when using a foreign key in a custom user model. I guess there is some problem with the Foreign Key.

There is no proper solution for django rest framework based app and I am using drf.

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone


class Region(models.Model):
    RegionName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    numGroups = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.RegionName


class Group(models.Model):
    GroupName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=True)
    Region = models.ForeignKey(
        Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="groups", null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.GroupName


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    GroupName = models.ForeignKey(
        Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="groupUser", null=True, blank=True)
    RegionName = models.ForeignKey(
        Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="regionUser", null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'GroupName','RegionName', ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

To assign `ForeignKey`s, you need a Serializer which is capable of relations:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/